# How do I send emails using blastula from shinyapps.io?

Tags: shinyapps, blastula

I'm trying to send email notifications from a shiny app using Gmail and the blastula package. What I want is that when a user presses a button, that sends an email notification to someone at my company so that they know to respond. This works when running the app locally, but when deployed to shinyapps.io, I am getting a login denied error (I've updated my gmail settings for this account to allow less secure apps, which is why it's working locally). Does anyone know how to get blastula functioning on shinyapps.io?

Answer (score 2):

I created an App Password to enhance security, as per the updated vignette from the authors of the bastula package, and it is working now!

https://github.com/rstudio/blastula/pull/283/commits/5d888972c0c788ac5c172403248e042489c4e1e6